# Efficiency of the search algorithm for kmp

Tags: algorithm

Based on [Efficiency of the search algorithm of KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Efficiency_of_the_search_algorithm),I really don't understand why the loop can execute at most 2n times.

The following is the pseudocode on wiki

```
algorithm kmp_search:
    input:
        an array of characters, S (the text to be searched)
        an array of characters, W (the word sought)
    output:
        an integer (the zero-based position in S at which W is found)

    define variables:
        an integer, m ← 0 (the beginning of the current match in S)
        an integer, i ← 0 (the position of the current character in W)
        an array of integers, T (the table, computed elsewhere)

    while m + i < length(S) do
        if W[i] = S[m + i] then
            if i = length(W) - 1 then
                return m
            let i ← i + 1
        else
            let m ← m + i - T[i]
            if T[i] > -1 then
                let i ← T[i]
            else
                let i ← 0

    (if we reach here, we have searched all of S unsuccessfully)
    return the length of S
```

I think the while loop executes at most n times, not 2n times. There are two branches in the loop. The first branch increase i but do not increase m. The second branch adds i-T[i] to m and i>T[i], so m will be increased. Thus m+i always increase in the while loop. I think the total time in the loop is at most n, why 2n times?

Comment: I have already described my problem in detail. it's my first time ask questions on this site. So sorry for breaking the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to visualize the algorithm as follows. You have a stationary string S, a movable string W directly under S, and a small rectangular sliding window that covers one character in both W and S. Initially the beginning of W is under the beginning of S, and the window covers initial characters of both. Each step of the algorithm is as follows:

1. If two characters covered by the sliding window match, move the window one position to the right. (If we were at the last character of W, the search is over, we have a success).
2. Otherwise, if the window is covering the first character of W, move both W and the window one position to the right.
3. Otherwise, move S to the right by the amount calculated from the table (does not really matter how much for this analysis; but it's a positive number).

I recommend doing that physically with two strips of paper and a paper window or a piece of glass!

It is easy to see that for each step 1 you can do step 3 at most once. The worst case is that you do step 3 exactly once for each step 1, and no step 2 is done at all. If you have the first character of W always match S, and the second character never match, that would be exactly the worst case. Thus, `W="ab", S="aaaaaaaaaaaaa.."`.

Answer (score 0):

The following passage is wrong:

> The second branch adds i-T[i] to m and i>T[i], so m will be increased.
>   Thus m+i always increase in the while loop.

Note that, in between, `i` is decreased to `T[i]`. So, in these cases, `m+i` stays constant.

Here is an example:

```
S: aaaab
W: aaaaa
T: 01234
```

The values `m` and `m+i` iterate as:

```
m   m+i
0   0
0   1
0   2
0   3
0   4
1   4
2   4
3   4
4   4
```

Basically, the following observation may help better understand the algorithm.
The value `m` is the start of the substring we look at, and `m+i` is the end of it.
More precisely, this substring `S[m..m+i)` is always a prefix of `W`.
On each step, we move either the start or the end of that substring to the right by at least one.

In fact, if we care for only the full matches (as opposed to, for example, searching for the longest prefix of `W` in `S`), we can indeed reduce the number of iterations to `n + 1` where `n = length(S)` by using the following modified loop condition:

```
while m + length(W) <= length(S) do
    ... (the same things)
```